# Excel _ Updating data in Sheet from by using data from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Being new to excel, I'm not able to write a macro which will update data in one of the columns from a master data reference.

For Example:
I have a sheet (Tran_Sheet) which has transaction data, along with the first name and last name of customers as separate columns.

I got another Sheet (Master_Data) which has all the first names and last names of the customers.

The data in Tran_Sheet , has noise and garbage values, hence some of the names have been misspelled.

I need to write a Macro such that the names will be updated in the Tran_Sheet based on the Master_Data as refernce.

I know this is just simple using an SQL query, but I need yto do it in Excel 2013.

Thank you!!!

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: A "join" is really a pain in Excel. Is it an absolute must to make this in Excel? You could possibly import your tables to MS Access and do the join there.

Comment: Why don't you just insert a formula into the Tran_Sheet which pulls the data from the Master_Data sheet? The combination of [INDEX / MATCH](http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/why-index-match-is-better-than-vlookup.htm) should work just fine. Once you have all the data on the Tran_Sheet you can remove the formulas with the respective values only. You can also do these 3 steps using VBA and it will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily execute a query on the current workbook:

```
Sub SQL_Example()

  ' query to compute the average score for each group
  Const SQL_SUM_SCORES_BY_GROUP = _
    "SELECT ref.Group, AVG(data.Score) AS Score " & _
    "FROM [Sheet1$] data INNER JOIN [Sheet2$] ref " & _
    "ON data.Name = ref.Name " & _
    "GROUP BY ref.Group "

  ' execute the query and write the results in a new sheet
  SqlExec ThisWorkbook, SQL_SUM_SCORES_BY_GROUP

End Sub

''
' Executes a query on a workbook.
' @source {Workbook}  Workbook loaded by the SQL engine
' @target {Worksheet} Optional, Worksheet to display the result
' @sql {String} SQL query
''
Sub SqlExec(source As Workbook, sql As String, Optional Target As Worksheet)
  Static rs As Object
  If rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

  ' build the connection string
  Dim conn$
  conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" _
       & ";Data Source=" & source.FullName _
       & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"

  ' insert a new worksheet if the target worksheet is null
  If Target Is Nothing Then
    Set Target = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
  End If

  ' execute the query
  rs.Open sql, conn

  ' copy the headers to the target sheet
  Target.Cells.Clear
  For i = 1 To rs.Fields.count
    Target.Cells(1, i).value = rs.Fields(i - 1).name
  Next

  ' copy the values to the target sheet
  Target.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs

  ' dispose
  rs.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a simple task and can't be solved either in a SQL Query or Excel without more details towards the type of noise in your data. It ends up rollin a dice when it comes towards correct personal data as its highly unstructured and people tend to forget about the time component.